# Fortran ifstream equivalent

Tags: c++, file-io, fortran

In C++, you can use std::ifstream to read from either a file or a string.  I would like to do the equivalent (or similar) in modern FORTRAN.

Specifically, I have an existing FORTRAN program which takes a file as an input and performs line-by-line read operations on it.  Can I easily convert this to parse either a file OR a string at runtime using the same logic?
For instance, if using `read` statements, they should work on either files or strings.

**Update**

Here is a simple snippet of C++ showing what I want to do.
Notice I call 1 Parse() function to import from file OR string:

```
void ImportFile( const std::string &file_name ) {
    std::istream is( file_name.c_str() );
    Parse( &is );
}

void ImportString( const std::string &str ) {
    std::stringbuf sbuf( str );
    std::istream is( &sbuf );
    Parse( &is );
}

void Parse( istream *is ) {
    std::string line;
    while( *is ) {
        getline( *is, line );

        // Process line ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a modern FORTRAN?

Comment: @Donald Sure, the most recent standard was approved in 2010.

Comment: Indeed, and the Fortran 2015 language revision is due in mid-2018 according to wikipedia page.  But being a Fortran novice, I would be happy with a solution using ANY Fortran version.

Comment: read *, write * and print * have been available since F77.

Comment: @cup - and how can the same `read` statement be used on both files AND strings?  C++ has the same interface for both types using `ifstream` and `getline`.

Comment: There's no such thing as an unformatted "line" (or you are being rather obscure).  Perhaps you meant "list directed".

Comment: __getline__ see @casey's example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but depending on your situation it may not be an easy conversion, and there are restrictions and requirements that may make it unsuitable.

User defined derived type input/output, introduced in Fortran 2003 (so you need a Fortran 2003 compiler), provides a single interface for file reading (and writing) operations, regardless of whether the originating file is internal or external (i.e. character variable or something on disk).  Client code simple invokes READ statements on the relevant unit or character variable, the source code path is common from there.

However, this approach requires that the data be read into an object of derived type (which might be of a type expressly written for this purpose) and that all input for an object be in the one record (i.e. array element if you are reading from a character variable, line if you are reading from a file).

For example

```
MODULE m
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE
  TYPE, PUBLIC :: t
    INTEGER :: a
    REAL :: b
    CHARACTER(:), ALLOCATABLE :: c
  CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE :: read_formatted
    GENERIC :: READ(FORMATTED) => read_formatted
  END TYPE t
CONTAINS
  ! For the sake of example, the form of our input is rather fixed.
  ! - a single character integer, followed by a blank.
  ! - a three character real, followed by a blank.
  ! - a one-or-more character character, followed by a blank or EOR.
  !
  ! i.e. "(I1,1X,F3.0,1X,A,:,1X,...)"

  SUBROUTINE read_formatted(dtv, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
    CLASS(t), INTENT(INOUT) :: dtv
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: unit
    CHARACTER(*), INTENT(IN) :: iotype
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: v_list(:)
    INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: iostat
    CHARACTER(*), INTENT(INOUT) :: iomsg

    CHARACTER :: ch
    CHARACTER(LEN(iomsg)) :: local_iomsg

    READ (unit, "(I1,1X)", IOSTAT=iostat, IOMSG=iomsg)  dtv%a
    IF (iostat /= 0) RETURN

    READ (unit, "(F3.0,1X)", IOSTAT=iostat, IOMSG=iomsg)  dtv%b
    IF (iostat /= 0) RETURN

    dtv%c = ''
    DO
      READ (unit, "(A)", IOSTAT=iostat, IOMSG=local_iomsg) ch
      IF (iostat < 0) EXIT
      IF (iostat /= 0) THEN
        iomsg = local_iomsg
        RETURN
      END IF
      IF (ch == '') EXIT
      dtv%c = dtv%c // ch
    END DO
    iostat = 0
  END SUBROUTINE read_formatted
END MODULE m

PROGRAM p
  USE m
  IMPLICIT NONE
  TYPE(T) :: x

  CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: input_string  &
      = '1 2.0 three'

  INTEGER :: unit
  CHARACTER(:), ALLOCATABLE :: string

  string = input_string

  ! Read from a string.
  READ (string, "(DT)") x
  PRINT *, x%a, x%b, x%c

  ! Prepare an example of an external file to read from.
  OPEN ( NEWUNIT=unit,  &
      STATUS='SCRATCH',  &
      ACTION='READWRITE' )
  WRITE (unit, "(A)") input_string
  REWIND unit

  ! Read from an external unit.
  READ (unit, "(DT)") x
  PRINT *, x%a, x%b, x%c

  CLOSE(unit)
END PROGRAM P
```

Comment: this is close to what I was looking for, albeit a little more complicated than I hoped!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this and without much change to your code as `read` can read from files or from character variables.

Consider the example code:

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer :: fin, varC, varC2
  real :: varA, varA2
  character(len=4) :: varB, varB2
  character(len=13) :: string_input = '1234.5 TEST 2'

  open(newunit=fin, file='filein.dat', form='formatted', access='stream', status='old')
  read(fin,*) varA, varB, varC
  print *, varA, varB, varC
  close(fin)

  read(string_input,*) varA2, varB2, varC2
  print *, varA2, varB2, varC2
end program test
```

and the input file `filein.dat`:

```
1234.5 TEST 2
```

When this program is executed, it prints:

```
1234.50000     TEST           2
1234.50000     TEST           2
```

You can see that whether the data is in a character variable or accessible via a file IO unit, the read is essentially the same.  For the file case, you provide the unit number, for the string case you provide the character variable containing the data.

---

The Fortran standards refer to IO on character variables as "internal files".  If your IO is record oriented you can provide a character scalar for each record or a character array with one record per array element.
One limitation of internal files is that you cannot use them in `open`, `close` or `inquire` statements.  This means you cannot associate your string with a numeric unit number.  The character variable itself must be used in the `read` statement rather than a unit number.  Accommodating this is probably the biggest hurdle (other than putting your data into character variables) to modifying your program to read from strings instead of files.

Comment: I would like the flexibility to read from either a string OR a file at runtime (e.g. depending on what the caller passes to the function).

Comment: And what you want to pass? A filename or unit number? You can easily make it work in a Fortran way. Just don't insist on a std library object. Pass Fortran primitives or make your own library object.

Comment: @tcdaniel you can use a generic interface to let them call the function with a unit number or a character variable and handle the cases with different specific procedures.  If you want to pass filename or string data, you can add a boolean that splits the logic from open/read/close vs read.  How do you want to handle it?

Comment: @casey - I have a lot of read statements, and I would rather not double them. I'm looking for a simple way to abstract out whether I'm calling with a file handle or a string. Is that possible?

Comment: @tcdaniel When you say file handle do you mean filename or unit number?

Comment: @Casey - I was thinking unit number, for the `read` statement (but any abstraction for reading which can use either method will do).

Comment: @Casey - What I really wanted was a function which took an object that masquerades as a stream from either a file or string. Based on these answers, it appears Fortran can't do this as easily as C++!

Comment: @tcdaniel as my example shows, you can easily do this as read will take either a unit number of a character variable.  The trick is how to encapsulate this into an abstraction, which isn't as straightforward as would be optimal due to the way the read intrinsic is called.  If your use calls read in consistent ways (e.g. similar number of arguments) you could write specific functions to handle each read case and put them behind a generic interface and convert all your read calls to call that generic instead.

Comment: and I'll add at that point (deciding on the abstraction and how to implement it) it gets out of scope from this question and probably deserves its own Q.

Comment: @casey Agreed. And for my needs, this is answered. I'm going to try reading the file into a single string and pass that into my Parse() subroutine.  So it will only work on a specific kind of string.